# How to Pass Function Results Into HTML Using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have the function main() which runs other functions inside. I have my final results displayed in "subtractboth()". How can i display the subtractboth() inside the HTML page that the flask script renders?

I tried calling {{main}} inside my html file but that did not produce any results.

test_index.html

```
<doctype html="">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Summary Billing Allocation Search</h1>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" style="border-spacing: 0;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; border-collapse: collapse; border: 3px solid white;">
<font face="calibri" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 20">
<tr bgcolor="#0097da" style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid white; color:white">
<th colspan = '5' align='center' style="padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;">Summary Bill Allocation 
Results</th>
</tr>
</font>
<font face="calibri" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18">
<tr bgcolor="#78c239" style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid white; padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right:5px; color:white">
    <th style="border-right: 2px solid white">Cash Date</th>
    <th style="border-right: 2px solid white">Name</th>
    <th style="border-right: 2px solid white">Master</th>
    <th style="border-right: 2px solid white">Subordinate</th>
    <th style="border-right: 2px solid white">Debit Amount</th>
</tr>
</font>
{{a}}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

library.py

```
@app.route('/results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    connect()
    masteracct = request.args.get('masteracct')
    cashdt = request.args.get('cashdt')
    billdt = request.args.get('billdt')
    allocation(connect(), cashdt, masteracct)
    statement(connect(), billdt, masteracct)
    a = subtractboth(statement(connect(),billdt, masteracct), allocation(connect(),cashdt, 
    masteracct))
    print(a)
    html = render_template('test_results.html')
    return html
```

Comment: I think that: html = render_template('test_results.html', a=a) should work

Comment: Check out [the documentation for `render_template()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.render_template).

Comment: @Marco I am getting "None" on my html page when i tried that.

Answer (score 3):

The part of main method where you actually render the template, you have to pass the value a which can be used in html code.

The change suggested is:

```
return render_template('test_results.html', a=a)
```